# 'java' command is working but 'javac' don't

Tags: java, java-8, javac

I have set path variables.

```
Variable: JAVA_HOME
Value: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101
Path: C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;
```

When I execute command 'java -version', output is

```
java version "1.8.0_102"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_102-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.102-b14, mixed mode)
```

But when I type 'javac -version', output is

```
'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Why javac ic not recognised?

PS: I have restarted my pc several times.

Comment: Can you run ```C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\javac.exe -version```?  Can you add C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin to your PATH environment variable.  Then start a new shell.  You don't need to reboot.

Comment: @pmcevoy12 Output:'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @rohit15079: So: `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\javac.exe" -version` (note the quotes). Just like any other time you have a filename with a space in it and want to use it on the command line.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for correcting.

Comment: @pmcevoy12 now, it freezes for 1-2 seconds and then prompt comes again.

Comment: @rohit15079: If the installation didn't fail, that won't just not output anything; it'll show `javac 1.8.0_101` or similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have installed both a separate JRE and a JDK, of different versions, and your path includes only the `bin` directory of the JRE. You've shown `JAVA_HOME` as including version 1.8.0_101, but the `-version` output you're seeing says 1.8.0_102, so clearly isn't from that installation.

I suggest finding and uninstalling the 1.8.0_101 JRE, then updating your `PATH` to include the two `bin` directories in the JDK installation. One of them will be `basepath\jdk\bin`, the other will be `basepath\jdk\jre\bin`. Include them in that order (JDK first). Then make sure `JAVA_HOME` points to that installation.

---

Having just installed JDK 1.8.0_101 on a Windows machine I had handy, I can confirm that it adds the JRE `bin` directory to the path but not the JDK `bin` directory. If you want the JDK `bin` directory in the path as well, add `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin` to the PATH via the control panel (changing the version number if necessary).

Comment: I have completely removed all versions and installed jdk 1.8 102u again. And added same path. But, problem is still there.

Comment: @rohit15079: See above.

Comment: I found these step by step instructions with screenshots helpful https://javatutorial.net/set-java-home-windows-10

Answer (score 0):

If java command is working and getting problem with javac. then first check in jdk's bin directory javac.exe file is there or not. If javac.exe file is exist then set JAVA_HOME as System variable.

Answer (score 0):

right click on `my computer` and select `properties`

1. in left side of opened window click on `Advanced system settings`
2. after system properties opened click on `Advanced` tab and then click `Environment Variables..`
3. in `System variables` section of `Environment Variables` windows set JAVA_HOME by click on `New` button.
4. Set below setting:
          Variable name : JAVA_HOME
          Variable value : C:\Java\jre1.8.0_92\;C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\
5. click ok in all Window

[image: Set Java_Home on Windows 7]

Also Maybe need to set JAVA_HOME in User variable section too